# Ошибка method not allowed

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Когда в url вписываю `domen/cart/add/2379` то выдаёт ошибку

```
'405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED. THIS URL CAN ONLY HANDLE THE FOLLOWING REQUEST METHODS: POST.',
```

товар добавляется в корзину если нажимать на кнопку `купить`, а если в `url` вписать то ошибка...
фреймворк `yii2`. 
Подскажите куда смотреть)

Comment: Сюда - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods и сюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#405

Comment: Видимо вызов данного метода доступен с помощью метода `POST`, а вы запрашиваете с помощью `GET`. `POST` - запрос просто сформировать с помощью форм, что у вас скорее всего и происходит, и кнопка у вас видимо `submit`. Простым способом сформировать POST-запрос с помощью адресной строки не получится.

Comment: Да, это верно) и всё же.. где можно и как поменять этот метод на кнопке, ищу и ничего примерно не могу найти

Comment: Зачем менять? Это некошерно и небезопасно.

Answer (score 0):

В сообщении об ошибке английским по белому написано, что данный адрес принимает только запросы методом POST, а "если в url вписать" - это метод GET.

Чтобы решить эту "проблему" надо перестать пытаться использовать HTTP методы не по назначению. То есть надо перестать "вписывать в url", а отправить POST запрос с помощью формы или яваскрипта.